# Как разбить текст на строки при условии?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеем отформатированный текст ,обычный тег параграфа и внутри не известное кол-во текста, пробел добавляется по css правилу `white-space:pre-wrap;`, как обернуть каждую строку в тег `span` т.е начало строки это отрывающий тег а конец строки закрывающий ...

```css
p{
white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
Hic eligendi, harum quidem consectetur rerum aut sunt 
delectus assumenda qui doloremque perferendis quod ducimus! 
Officiis ducimus impedit veniam,quia similique maxime quidem 
veritatis adipisci minima laboriosam molestiae tenetur atque 
consectetur eaque optio fuga eveniet suscipit culpa reprehenderit  </p>
```

[оригинальный вопрос который заинтересовал](https://toster.ru/q/494142)

Comment: Больше интересует не как разбить текст, а зачем это нужно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский для анимации

Comment: Для таких целей есть более адекватные подходы, а не через пень колоду)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я суть не знаю .. по ссылке есть моя переписка с автором вопроса , меня заинтересовало именно как обернуть строку в тег

Comment: Понятно. Ну задача на первый взгляд интересная, но абсолютно бесполезная) Не практическая.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а мне  кажется очень практично это ...

Comment: Нет же)) потому что https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767541/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment1194744_767541

Comment: Единственное что приходит в голову ... обернуть сначала каждое слово в `span`, а затем по сочетанию условий переноса и `offset.top` ( O_o ) определять какие куски надо объединить ... но да, это какая-то дичь xDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev я уже долго борюсь с этим .... вопрос меня только под толкнул заново вернутся к этому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выглядит конечно это все странно, но ничего лучше я придумать не сумел xDD

```js
for(const node of document.getElementsByTagName('p')) {
  ultimateLineWrapperMachine3000(node);
}

function ultimateLineWrapperMachine3000( node ) {
  const paragraphContent = node.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, ''); // Удаляем лишние пробелы получившиеся из-за форматирования html
  const paragrapthWrappedWords = paragraphContent.replace(/(\S+)/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>'); // Оборачиваем все слова вместе с символами

  node.innerHTML = paragrapthWrappedWords;

  const wrappedWords = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
  const arrayOfWordNodes = Object.keys(wrappedWords).map(k => wrappedWords[k]);
  let currLineTop = 0;
  let finalHTML = '';

  arrayOfWordNodes.forEach(( node, index ) => {
    const nodeTop = node.offsetTop;

    finalHTML += ''
    + ( index !== 0 && currLineTop !== nodeTop ? '</span>' : ' ' )
    + ( index === 0 || currLineTop !== nodeTop ? '<span class="line">' : '' )
    + node.innerHTML;

    currLineTop = nodeTop;
  });

  node.innerHTML = finalHTML.trim();
}
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  white-space:pre-wrap;
}

p.short {
  width: 150px;
}

.line { display: block; }

.line:nth-child(2n-1) { background-color: yellow; }
.line:nth-child(2n) { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Hic eligendi, harum quidem consectetur rerum aut sunt 
  delectus assumenda qui doloremque perferendis quod ducimus! 
  Officiis ducimus impedit veniam,quia similique maxime quidem 
  veritatis adipisci minima laboriosam molestiae tenetur atque 
  consectetur eaque optio fuga eveniet suscipit culpa reprehenderit
</p>

<p class="short">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Hic eligendi, harum quidem consectetur rerum aut sunt 
  delectus assumenda qui doloremque perferendis quod ducimus! 
  Officiis ducimus impedit veniam,quia similique maxime quidem 
  veritatis adipisci minima laboriosam molestiae tenetur atque 
  consectetur eaque optio fuga eveniet suscipit culpa reprehenderit
</p>
```

Comment: а чё не отображается background-color ? это уже просто интересно

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, хм, это странно, у меня вроде отображается. Строки то обернулись? Может у вас браузер es6 не поддерживает?

Comment: у меня Edge , но я уже убеждаюсь что есть некоторые плюшки которые не работают

Comment: да обернулось ... это волшебство , чес слово ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, если обернулось, но бекграунда нет, то это точно что-то очень странное О_о

Comment: а это что такое ? ultimateLineWrapperMachine3000

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, эээм, ну собственно функция которая создает это волшебство (разбивает все на строки и оборачивает) xDD

Comment: вот у меня  с регулярками трудности ... увидел replace и ужаснулся

Comment: `node.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '')` - это что-то типа [string.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) только для каждой строки (сделано только для того, что бы не заморачиваться и не нарушать форматирование в html'е), а второе это просто оборачивание всего что не пробел и не перенос строки в `span`